# Why does this simple loop fail in netbeans, java (JFRAME)?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I don't program in java but decided to try it by making a jframe in netbeans. In the auto generated initComponent() method this for-loop fails to run, telling me the following things:

- illegal start of type
- cannot find symbol: class i

  ```
  friendList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
      URL url = getClass().getResource("friends");
      File folder = new File(url.getPath());
      File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
      String[] elements = new String[listOfFiles.length];
      for(int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length;i++) {
          elements[i] = (listOfFiles[i].getName());
  }
  ```

  Can anyone explain?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to define executable code out side of an executable context (method or constructor)

Comment: If you use `URL url = getClass().getResource("friends");`, then `File folder = new File(url.getPath());` is pointless, as the resource may not be accessible as a file

Comment: Well, I take it the problem with the loop is that it cant be executed in the initComponent() method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are trying you call a for loop outside of a function.
What the code

```
new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {}
```

does is create an anonymous subclass. Think of it like this:

```
class (anonymous) extends javax.swing.AbstractListModel{
    URL url = getClass().getResource("friends");
    File folder = new File(url.getPath());
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    String[] elements = new String[listOfFiles.length];
    for(int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length;i++) {
        elements[i] = (listOfFiles[i].getName());
}
```

You can see where that would cause problems
The easiest way to fix it is to add an initializer, giving you the following fixed code:

```
friendList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
    URL url = getClass().getResource("friends");
    File folder = new File(url.getPath());
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    String[] elements = new String[listOfFiles.length];
    {
        for(int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length;i++) {
            elements[i] = (listOfFiles[i].getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if we can untangle this...

Your basic problem seems to be that you're trying to define executable code out side of an executable context (method or constructor).

`URL url = getClass().getResource("friends");` followed by `File folder = new File(url.getPath());` makes no sense, as the purpose of using `getResource` is to find a resource which may or may not exist on the disk. In most cases it's embedded within your applications jar context.

I "think" what you're trying to do is find a directory, which could be accomplished using something more like...

```
File folder = new File("friends");
```

This assumes that the directory `friends` is within the same execution context as your program.

Next, instead of creating an `AbstractListModel` and trying to run code out side of a executable context, you could simply create a `DefaultListModel` and fill it like so:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
for(int i=0; i<listOfFiles.length;i++) {
    model.addElement(listOfFiles[i].getName());
}
friendList.setModel(model);
```

As an example.

Perhaps you should take some more time to learn the basics of the language before plunging head long into the complexities of a GUI, it will help greatly with figuring these kinds of problems ... as a friendly suggestion.